# Radium (React) - passing style values as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a custom React component with inline styling using Radium. I have React, Radium and Meteor working perfectly apart of this little thing.

What I want to achieve:

```
<div style={styles.tile}>
...
var styles = {
tile: {
    background: this.props.color
}
```

And then create new components in the parent like this:

```
<Tile color="#A200FF"></Tile>
```

What I get is:

```
Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0.0.0.0.$/=11.0.$=10.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.
```

Now if I remove `this.props.color` and type in `'#FF0000'` it will work perfectly fine. But I really need to be able to pass the color to the component from the parent.

As I said: Meteor, React and Radium are working perfectly fine in other places of the app.

Any ideas how to achieve what I want to build? Is it Radium's bug or is it me not understanding something important about it?